# NSTableview and SearchField

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nssearchfield

I have an action for searching in NSMutableArray with name searcharray, which is equal to array with which NSTableView are connected.And I wrote a method for adding items to TableView just by sending NSMutableArray to my method. 
The problem is that after searching if I delete what I have typed in SearchField and SearchField is empty, the compiler doesn't feel that it's empty and my TableView getting empty too, but due my code it's have to be with data from searcharray.
Here is my code:

```
#import "myTableViewAppDelegate.h"

@implementation myTableViewAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize searcharray;


-(void)addItems:(NSMutableArray *)ar{
    array = ar;
    [array retain];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return (int)[array count];
}
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
            row:(int)row
{
    return [array objectAtIndex:row];
}



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSMutableArray *animals = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cat", @"Dog", @"Fish", @"Squirrel", @"Bear", @"Turtle", nil] retain];
    NSLog(@"%@",animals);
    searcharray = animals;
    [self addItems:animals];

}

- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {
    //NSLog(@"%@",searcharray);
    NSString *filter = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[search stringValue]];
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (filter != nil) {
      for (NSString *item in searcharray) {
        if ([item rangeOfString:[search stringValue]].location !=NSNotFound ) {
            NSLog(@"Item %@ contains %@",item,[search stringValue]);
            [result addObject:item];
        }
    }  
    }
    else{
    result = searcharray;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    [self addItems:result];
    [result release];
    [filter release];
}
@end
```

Comment: Well, just magic dance with tambourine around the computer so far :)
But, yeah , I have played with blocks if and else, checked all variables while app is running and everything looks completely fine to me. I have no idea why it doesn't work and tableview is empty :(

Comment: I used similar routine in C# before and that worked there. I'm new to Objective-C, so maybe there is some stuff which I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
if (filter != nil || filter.length != 0)
```

I don't know why, but just checking variable equal to NULL wasn't enough....

Comment: `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[search stringValue]]` will only return nil if it's not able to allocate memory. You can change the test to `if ([filter length])`. Sending a message to a nil object always returns 0 so this will evaluate to false if `filter` is nil or if `length` is 0.